# Can't install dbus-python using pip because of numerous undefined references. Why not?

Tags: pip, linker-errors

I'm struggling to get a Python 3.10.11 installation on OpenSuSE 15.4 (on x86_64) built from source equipped with the `dbus-python` package. Installing it using `pip` does not work because the linker invoked by the `wheel` process can't find numerous libraries and then complains about undefined references. See the (very long) complete output:

```bash
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  cd /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin    
╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin  
╰─➤  source activate                                              
(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin  
             ╰─➤  pip install -v "dbus-python; sys_platform=='linux'"      
Using pip 23.1.2 from /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Collecting dbus-python
  Using cached dbus-python-1.3.2.tar.gz (605 kB)
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Using pip 23.1.2 from /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
  Collecting meson-python>=0.8.1
    Using cached meson_python-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
  Collecting meson>=0.60.0
    Using cached meson-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (916 kB)
  Collecting ninja
    Using cached ninja-1.11.1-py2.py3-none-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (145 kB)
  Collecting patchelf
    Using cached patchelf-0.17.2.1-py2.py3-none-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl (425 kB)
  Collecting setuptools
    Downloading setuptools-67.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
       ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 9.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
  Collecting pyproject-metadata>=0.7.1 (from meson-python>=0.8.1)
    Using cached pyproject_metadata-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
  Collecting tomli>=1.0.0 (from meson-python>=0.8.1)
    Using cached tomli-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
  Collecting packaging>=19.0 (from pyproject-metadata>=0.7.1->meson-python>=0.8.1)
    Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
  Installing collected packages: patchelf, ninja, wheel, tomli, setuptools, packaging, meson, pyproject-metadata, meson-python
    changing mode of /tmp/pip-build-env-p0b_38gm/overlay/bin/ninja to 755
    changing mode of /tmp/pip-build-env-p0b_38gm/overlay/bin/wheel to 755
    changing mode of /tmp/pip-build-env-p0b_38gm/overlay/bin/meson to 755
  Successfully installed meson-1.1.0 meson-python-0.13.1 ninja-1.11.1 packaging-23.1 patchelf-0.17.2.1 pyproject-metadata-0.7.1 setuptools-67.8.0 tomli-2.0.1 wheel-0.40.0
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765 /tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765/.mesonpy-_zq4ufqy/build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765/.mesonpy-_zq4ufqy/build/meson-python-native-file.ini
  The Meson build system
  Version: 1.1.0
  Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765
  Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765/.mesonpy-_zq4ufqy/build
  Build type: native build
  Project name: dbus-python
  Project version: 1.3.2
  C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0")
  C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.39.0.20220810-150100
  Host machine cpu family: x86_64
  Host machine cpu: x86_64
  Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-declaration-after-statement: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-inline: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-redundant-decls: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-switch-default: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-write-strings: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdouble-promotion: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-cond: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnull-dereference: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-enum: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wjump-misses-init: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-sign: YES
  Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES
  Configuring _dbus-python-config.h using configuration

  Executing subproject dbus-gmain

  dbus-gmain| Project name: dbus-gmain
  dbus-gmain| Project version: undefined
  dbus-gmain| C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 7.5.0 "cc (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0")
  dbus-gmain| C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.39.0.20220810-150100
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -fno-common: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-missing-field-initializers: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wcast-align: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdouble-promotion: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-branches: YES
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wduplicated-cond: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wfloat-equal: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-nonliteral: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat-security: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wformat=2: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Winit-self: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wlogical-op: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-declarations: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-format-attribute: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-include-dirs: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-noreturn: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnull-dereference: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpacked: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-arith: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wredundant-decls: YES
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wshadow: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-default: YES
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wswitch-enum: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wundef: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wunused-but-set-variable: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wwrite-strings: YES
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wdeclaration-after-statement: YES
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wjump-misses-init: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wmissing-prototypes: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wnested-externs: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wold-style-definition: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wpointer-sign: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Compiler for C supports arguments -Wstrict-prototypes: YES (cached)
  dbus-gmain| Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
  dbus-gmain| Run-time dependency dbus-1 found: YES 1.12.2
  dbus-gmain| Run-time dependency glib-2.0 found: YES 2.70.5
  dbus-gmain| Run-time dependency gthread-2.0 found: YES 2.70.5
  dbus-gmain| Program dbus-run-session found: YES (/usr/bin/dbus-run-session)
  dbus-gmain| Build targets in project: 1
  dbus-gmain| Subproject dbus-gmain finished.

  Program python found: YES (/home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python)
  Dependency dbus-1 found: YES 1.12.2 (cached)
  Configuring TestSuitePythonService.service using configuration
  Configuring tmp-session-bus.conf using configuration
  Program dbus-run-session found: YES (/usr/bin/dbus-run-session)
  Build targets in project: 5

  dbus-python 1.3.2

    Subprojects
      dbus-gmain  : YES

    User defined options
      Native files: /tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765/.mesonpy-_zq4ufqy/build/meson-python-native-file.ini
      buildtype   : release
      b_ndebug    : if-release
      b_vscrt     : md

  Found ninja-1.11.1.git.kitware.jobserver-1 at /tmp/pip-build-env-p0b_38gm/overlay/bin/ninja
  + /tmp/pip-build-env-p0b_38gm/overlay/bin/ninja
  [1/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_debug.c.o
  [2/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_generic.c.o
  [3/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_libdbusconn.c.o
  [4/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_mainloop.c.o
  [5/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_unixfd.c.o
  [6/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_bytes.c.o
  [7/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_exceptions.c.o
  [8/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_bus.c.o
  [9/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_float.c.o
  [10/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_message-get-args.c.o
  [11/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_conn.c.o
  [12/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_int.c.o
  [13/32] Compiling C object subprojects/dbus-gmain/libdbus-gmain.a.p/dbus-gmain.c.o
  [14/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_abstract.c.o
  [15/32] Linking static target subprojects/dbus-gmain/libdbus-gmain.a
  [16/32] Compiling C object test/test-import-repeatedly.p/import-repeatedly.c.o
  [17/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_containers.c.o
  [18/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_signature.c.o
  [19/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_string.c.o
  [20/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_module.c.o
  [21/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_conn-methods.c.o
  [22/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_pending-call.c.o
  [23/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_validation.c.o
  [24/32] Compiling C object _dbus_glib_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_glib_bindings_module.c.o
  [25/32] Compiling C object test/dbus_py_test.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_py_test.c.o
  [26/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_message.c.o
  [27/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_server.c.o
  [28/32] Linking target test/dbus_py_test.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  [29/32] Linking target _dbus_glib_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  [30/32] Compiling C object _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so.p/dbus_bindings_message-append.c.o
  [31/32] Linking target _dbus_bindings.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  [32/32] Linking target test/test-import-repeatedly
  FAILED: test/test-import-repeatedly
  cc  -o test/test-import-repeatedly test/test-import-repeatedly.p/import-repeatedly.c.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--start-group /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a -Wl,--end-group
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(thread.o): in function `init_condattr':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Python/thread_pthread.h:157: undefined reference to `pthread_condattr_setclock'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(thread.o): in function `PyThread_tss_create':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Python/thread_pthread.h:894: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(thread.o): in function `PyThread_tss_set':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Python/thread_pthread.h:920: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'

# Hundreds of undefined references appear here, but SO won't let me paste all of them.

  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1696: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_hmac_digest_size':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1571: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_get_md'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1571: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_size'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1571: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_get_md'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1571: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_size'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_hashlib_HMAC_copy_impl':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1620: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1625: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1631: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_hmac_update':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1592: undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1596: undefined reference to `HMAC_Update'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_tscmp':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1955: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_memcmp'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1955: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_memcmp'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_hashlib_hmac_get_block_size':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1763: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_get_md'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1767: undefined reference to `EVP_MD_block_size'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_hashlib_hmac_new_impl':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1518: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_new'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1524: undefined reference to `HMAC_Init_ex'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1552: undefined reference to `HMAC_CTX_free'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `_hashlib_hmac_singleshot_impl':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:1459: undefined reference to `HMAC'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../dist/lib64/libpython3.10.a(_hashopenssl.o): in function `EVP_hash':
  /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:441: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:441: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
  /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/build/../Modules/_hashopenssl.c:441: undefined reference to `EVP_DigestUpdate'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin/python /home/jacek/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpfb7kix21
  cwd: /tmp/pip-install-fd186k_8/dbus-python_4d01d5bf4b104f56bf59213166b07765
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

(displaycal) ╭─jacek@epica ~/bin/tmp/Python-3.10.11/dist/displaycal/bin  
             ╰─➤                                                                        1 ↵
```

What prevents the build process from finding the necessary libraries? Is it OpenSSL, which causes trouble here? I've got OpenSSL 1.1.1 (including header files), which comes with OpenSuSE 15.4. Installation dir is `/usr/lib64`. Of course I've built Python with the `--with-ssl` option.